# Approximation error from using the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

> A bank accepts rolls of pennies and gives 50 cents credit to a customer without counting the contents.
>   Assume that a roll contains 49 pennies 30 percent of the time, 50 pennies 60 percent of the time, and 51
>   pennies 10 percent of the time. Estimate the probability that the bank will lose more than 25 cents in 100 rolls.

The [solution (first problem part b)](https://emilyb.public.iastate.edu/stat330/homework%20solutions/hw8sols09.pdf) has:

> $P(Z > 25) = 1 − P(Z ≤ 25) = 1 − N_{20,36}(25) = 1 − N_{0,1}(5/6) = 0.2023$

With $Z$ having a mean of $100\mu = 20$ and variance of $100\sigma^2 = 36$. $\mu$ is the expected loss per roll and $\sigma^2$ the variance of the losses per roll (loss is positive).

However, since $P(Z>25) = P(Z \geq 26) = P(Z^* \geq 1)$, this is equal to $0.1587$. Are both methods valid, as there's a $0.0437$ difference (which to me is quite large) between the two results. Is this an approximation error or am I doing something wrong / unconventional?

Comment: If I calculate the expected value of one roll I get $49.8$ and a variance of $0.36$ (This seems equal to yours).

Comment: I should have linked the solutions, the expected value calculated is for expected losses. For each trial the expected loss is 0.2 so for 100 trials it is 20. Post is edited.

Comment: Hint: If $Z$ is a $\textrm{continuous variable}$ then $P(Z>z)=P(Z\geq z)$

Comment: The problem is that you are approximating a discrete random variable by a normal (very similar to a normal approximation of a binomial). If you want, you could change $P(Z>25)$ to $P(Z>25+t)$ where $0\leq t < 1.$

Comment: FWIW, I simulated this $1,000,000$ times and I got $P(loss \gt 25) = 0.178783$ which is about halfway between your answer and the official answer. So I think both ways are valid. It is matter of taste: whether you want a conservative estimate or a more loose one.